# How to retain line breaks in the HTML5 code block?

Tags: asp.net, html

I've got this in a Default.aspx page:

```
   <code>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#clickThis").click(function () {
                alert("Hallo die Welt!");
            });
        });
   </code>
```

Yet it displays as:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { $("#clickThis").click(function () { alert("Hallo die Welt!"); }); });
```

...which is nice when real estate is an issue, but for readability, I would like it to display the code exactly as contained within the  tag. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind everything inside `<code>` tags respecting whitespace, use this CSS:

```
code {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/yDNA5/).

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
<pre>
<code>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#clickThis").click(function () {
            alert("Hallo die Welt!");
        });
    });
</code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put < pre> tags around the < code> tags.